# jquery-ui autocompletion does not work properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get some autocompletion from a php file, but it doesnt work nice..

this is the html file:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags" />
</div>
```

this is the script

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: "test.php", 
        autoFocus : true,
        dataType: "json"

    });
});
</script>
```

and there is the test.php file:

```
<?

 $term = $_REQUEST['term']; 

 $result = array();

 $arr['id'] = "pippo";
 $arr['value'] = "pippo";

 array_push($result, $arr);

 $arr['id'] = "topo";

 $arr['value'] = "topo";

 array_push($result, $arr);

echo json_encode($result);

 ?>
```

why the hell if I type **T** I get both **topo** and **pippo**?

Comment: Your remote data source (the PHP code) is supposed to return only the items matching the `term` request variable, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are telling the server to return all the results:

```
 $arr['id'] = "pippo";
 $arr['value'] = "pippo";    
 array_push($result, $arr);    
 $arr['id'] = "topo";    
 $arr['value'] = "topo";    
 array_push($result, $arr);
```

not just those that match